# Python dictionary get method in assignment

Tags: python, syntax-error

All,

I'm looping over a dictionary and counting the values that occur. To do this, I'm using the get method in the assignment statement for another dictionary. This returns a syntax error "can't assign to function call"

```
counts = {}
mydict = {'a':[1,2,5], 'b': [1,2,10]}
for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
    counts(value[1]) = counts.get(value[1], 0) + 1
```

Why would the assignment try to point to the function, rather than the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
counts = {}
mydict = {'a':[1,2,5], 'b': [1,2,10]}
for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
    counts[value[1]] = counts.get(value[1], 0) + 1
```

You need brackets, not parenthesis, to get an item from a dictionary.

Also, You're doing this the hard way.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# automatically start each count at zero
counts = defaultdict(int)
# we only need the values, not the keys
for value in mydict.itervalues(): 
    # add one to the count for this item
    counts[value[1]] += 1
```

or

```
# only on Python 2.7 or newer
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(value[1] for value in mydict.itervalues())
```

Comment: Python needs blocks to be indented.  Your `for` body is not indented.

Comment: Python needs indentation? I never would have known!! It was just a typo, obviously.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I have got to stop switching languages in the middle of the work day. Also, thanks for pointing out the defaultdict bit, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `counts(value[1]) = ...` you want `counts[value[1]] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
counts(value[1])
```

to this:

```
counts[value[1]]
```

Code looks like this:

```
counts = {}
mydict = {'a':[1,2,5], 'b': [1,2,10]}
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    counts[value[1]] = counts.get(value[1], 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counts[value[1]] = counts.get(value[1], 0) + 1
```

should be

```
counts[value[1]] = counts.get(value[1], 0) + 1
```